# How to set a cache control for S3 files uploaded through Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I want to set a cache-control to files uploaded to S3 through Active Storage.

There is this line in the rails repo ([link here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb)) :

```
object_for(key).put(body: io, content_md5: checksum, content_type: content_type, **upload_options)
```

So i know that if there is the `:cache_control` key in **upload_options it could work. (link to aws reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method))

How to properly set something in upload_options?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in `storage.yml`, add an `upload:` config :

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  upload:
    cache_control: 'private, max-age=31536000'
```

Comment: hi @Nicolas Maloeurve, thanks for the answer, can you also share some link to the documentation where we can find more information about what other settings are available and can be set in storage.yml, would be very helpful, Thanks.

Comment: @opensource-developer I remember that I had to dig in the Rails repository, and that there is not a lot of documentation about this

Comment: thanks for your reply @Nicolas Maloeuvre, i see an option to change the setting via google cloud platform and apply cache setting to bucket, but not sure, if there is a way to do it programmatically

Comment: I did'n find the official documentation but I found a post that describes how this setting works: https://bitcrowd.dev/caching-with-active-storage